AGGrid v32 Row Selection
How do we control the position of the checkboxes on the AGGrid community from v32 onwards?  I am coming from v29.
In V29 the selection column is defined on the coldef
{
        hide: false,
        editable: false,
        maxWidth: 45,
        checkboxSelection: true,
        sortable: false,
        suppressMenu: true,
        filter: false,
        headerCheckboxSelection: true,
        headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
        pinned: true,
        resizable: false,
}

In v32, it seemed we are not supposed to define it on the coldef anymore but there is a new selection property on the AGGridReact.  checkboxSelection and headerCheckboxSelection on the ColDef object are both marked as deprecated.
<AgGridReact
   selection={{
      mode: 'multiRow',
   ...
   }}
/>

On v29, we can define which column the checkboxes goes to because we can insert the entry in order with the rest of the coldefs
How do I do that with v32.  Or is having it as part of the coldef still supported.  I cannot find any examples on the AGGrid documentation site.  All the examples are using selection props with very simple configurations.
Tried using the coldef like before but lots of deprecated props there and it is complaining in TypeScript
